# How to show in simulations that a method estimates standard errors well?

Tags: bootstrap, simulation, standard-error

I would like to compare several ways of computing standard errors for some quantities using simulations, but I don't know what metric should I use for that. I know that for confidence intervals I can calculate coverage and check if it is at the nominal level and see if some method does not underestimate or overestimate confidence intervals. Is there something similar for standard errors?

One idea would be to calculate confidence intervals based on the estimated standard errors, but I would like to validate standard errors directly, also for computation reasons since i am using bootstrap and it is said that fewer replications are needed to estimate standard errors than to estimate confidence intervals

Comment: Begin, then, by quantifying your intended interpretation of a standard error, and go on from there.

Comment: @whuber this might indeed be a good starting point for an answer